# A couple of questions: Convergence in probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

I am strugling to prove the following two statements. I would much appreciate it if anyone can help me on these please. Everything is real-valued.

$\bf{\text{Statement 1 }}$. If $X_n/a_n$ is bounded in probability where $a_n\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, then $X_n\overset{P}\rightarrow\infty$ (as in $P(X_n>r)\rightarrow 1$ for all $r>0$).

I was trying to prove this in the similar way as in how we would do when $a_n\rightarrow 0$ (in which case $X_n=o_p(1)$). So something like as follows: Since $X_n=O_P(a_n)$, there exists a finite value $M_{\epsilon}>0$ such that $P(|X_n|>M_{\epsilon}a_n)<\epsilon$. Now, we take $n_0(\epsilon)$, sufficiently large, so that for $n\geq n_0(\epsilon)$ we have $M_{\epsilon}a_n>\delta$. Then,
\begin{equation}
P(|X_n|<\delta) \leq P(|X_n|<a_nM)<1-\epsilon....
\end{equation}
I feel I am almost there, but I am not quite sure how to proceed.

$\bf{\text{Statement 2}}$. If $X_n\overset{P}\rightarrow\infty$ , then $X_n^2/(X_n^2+c)\overset{P}\rightarrow 1$ where $c$ is some positive constant.

I am not sure what kind of "trick" I need to use when spliting the probability.

Thank you

Comment: $Z_n \to Z$ in probability if and only if every subsequence of $(Z_n)$ has  a further  subsequence converging a.s. to $Z$. For a.s convergence Statements 1) and 2) are both obvious.

Comment: Where did these statements come from? For 1, take $X_n=1$ for all $n$ and $a_n=n$. Then $X_n/a_n\overset{P}{\to}0$, but $X_n/a_n$ is bounded in probability (and in fact is just bounded). For Statement 2, take $X_n=n$ and$Y_n=n^2$. Then $X_n\overset{P}{\to}\infty$, $Y_n\overset{P}{\to}\infty$, and $X_n/(Y_n+c)\overset{P}{\to}0$ for any positive constant $c$. In fact, all statements about convergence in probability can be replaced with a.s. Both statements appear false to me.

Comment: Sorry there was an error in the second statement; now corrected...

Comment: What about the first one, which also seems to be false?

Comment: It's more like a conjecture of mine. Do you think the amended second statement is also false?

Comment: Agree with @bangs -- I there are clear counterexamples to (1) so its fasle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement 1: Having $X_n/a_n$ be bounded isn't what we want, because that says $X_n$ isn't too big. What we would rather have is that $a_n/X_n$ is bounded, **or** that $X_n/a_n$ is (non-negative) and bounded away from zero. Those are two ways to guarantee that $X_n$ is not too small.

Statement 1': Suppose that $a_n\to \infty$ and for some $\varepsilon>0$, $\lim_n \mathbb{P}(X_n/a_n<\varepsilon)=0$.  Then $X_n\overset{\mathbb{P}}{\to}\infty$.

Proof: Fix $r\in \mathbb{R}$.   Fix $\delta>0$ and $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>n_0$, $\mathbb{P}(X_n/a_n<\varepsilon)<\delta$ and $a_n>r/\varepsilon$.  Then for all $n>n_0$, $$\{X_n<r\} = \{X_n/a_n<r/a_n\}\subset \{X_n/a_n<\varepsilon\}, $$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n<r)\leqslant \mathbb{P}(X_n/a_n<\varepsilon)<\delta$.

Amended statement 2 is correct as written.

Proof: For any $c>0$, $X_n^2/(X_n^2+c)\leqslant 1$. Fix $a<1$ and fix $\varepsilon>0$ such that $1/(1+\varepsilon)>a$.  Fix $\delta>0$ and $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_n<\sqrt{c/\varepsilon})<\delta$ for all $n>n_0$.  Note that \begin{align*} \Bigl\{\frac{X^2_n}{X^2_n+c}\leqslant a\Bigl\} & \subset \Bigl\{\frac{1}{1+c/X^2_n}\leqslant \frac{1}{1+\varepsilon}\Bigl\} = \Bigl\{\frac{c}{X^2_n}\geqslant \varepsilon\Bigl\} \\ & = \Bigl\{X_n^2\leqslant c/\varepsilon\Bigl\} \subset\Bigl\{X_n\leqslant \sqrt{c/\varepsilon}\Bigl\},\end{align*} which has probability less than $\delta$.

Comment: Thank you very much @bangs